# Best way to use a string as a bool

Tags: c#

I have a method like this:

```
public void Method(bool value)
{
}
```

Now I want to call this method with a value parsed from an xml file (*.loadtest) which is a string:

```
<ContextParameter Name="paratemeter" Value="True" />
```

So, should I do this from the caller:

```
if(parameter.Equals("True")
    Method(true);
else
    Method(false);
```

or should I refactor the `Method` to get as parameter a string and do the check in there?

Comment: Why don't you call simply `Method(parameter.Equals("True"));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should keep

- the conversion from strings to actual method parameters and
- the actual "work to be done"

in two separate methods. It keeps your methods short and, thus, your code readable.

Answer (score 3):

I would use `bool.Parse(string)`

Answer (score 2):

Never use `bool.Parse` unless you have 100% control over the input.

Always use the `TryParse` methods when you are dealing with user input regardless.

```
bool result;
if(!bool.TryParse(value, out result))
   throw new Exception("There was a problem with the config.. etc..");

Method(result);
```

Comment: If you just want to throw an exception, bool.TryParse will throw a "nice" FormatException for you.

Comment: The exception there was an example on how you can throw something explicit. The negation has been added, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Is your object going to be directly populated by the config ? If so, get it to accept a string. Otherwise, parse the string separately and maintain your 'bool'-parameterised method.

I would perhaps check that you get a valid string e.g. "True"/"False" and throw an exception if you don't. Otherwise someone will provide "true" and you'll interpret it as `FALSE`.

You may choose (as a related point) to be relatively tolerant in what you accept (e.g. trim the string of whitespace etc.)

Answer (score 1):

> or should I refactor the Method to get as parameter a string and do the check in there?

No. Single responsibility. The method should not be the one to do parameter conversion. You could create an overload accepting a string parameter to do that, which then calls the impmlementation accepting a boolean, but then you'll have to do that for every method that requires a non-string configuration parameter.

It's better to do the conversion in one place, and call it like:

```
bool param = Configuration.GetBoolParameter("ParameterName");
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer getting rid of the string as soon as possible. It's a limitation of the XML, no need to transfer the limitation to the "contract" of your method(s).

As for the comparison, I'd say the most robust would be something like

```
var parsedBool = parameter.ToUpper() == "TRUE";
```

Comment: That would assume any unvalid string parses to false.

Answer (score 0):

```
Method(bool.Parse(parameter));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd retain the contract that says "I need a bool".

Parse the XML, turn that text value into a bool using the method recommended above, and pass that.

Answer (score 0):

I would never trust that this kind of input would be safe enough to just pass to bool.Parse
Instead I would do something more fail safe like this positive parsing with a negative fallback.

```
bool getBoolean(string input) {
  var value = false;
  bool.TryParse(input ?? string.Empty,out value);
  return value;
}
```